# Minimization of Boolean functions

Tags: logic, optimization, boolean-algebra

Given a Boolean function represented in DNF, I am looking for a way to "minimize" its claues, in the sense that each clause contains only the variables it has to. For example, in

$$\phi = a + (b* \tilde a)$$

the second clause can be simply $b$. This is not a minimization in the "regular" sense (reducing the number of clauses). Are there any approaches on this problem?

Comment: I don't understand your example.  So the clauses (which in this case are conjunctions) are $a$ and $ab$?  And why can the $ab$ clause be minmized to $b$? Can you please explain?

Comment: Edited. The clauses are a, and: not a, b. Which has the same truth table as a+b, so the not a in the second clause is not necessary

Comment: Ah!  Ok, that makes sense.  That example is actually an instance of reduction: if you have a literal (a single proposition or negation thereof),  then you can remove its complement from all the other clauses.  And for non-literals, something similar holds, e.g. $xy + xy'z = xy +xz$. Also, you can get rid of some terms completely using absorption: $x +xy= x$. So, you can try some of those simplifications.  Beyond that ... See Fabio's good answer below!

Comment: If I have a literal, why can I remove its complement from all other clauses? Take a*(1-b)+bc. You can't remove the b in the second clause

Comment: I meant if you have a literal all by itself. So (1-b) + bc = (1-b) + c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is a *prime cover* of the function $\phi$ given a DNF for it.  That is, a cover made of prime implicants.

A classic reference for similar problems is *Logic Minimization Algorithms for VLSI Synthesis* by Brayton, Hachtel, McMullen, and Sangiovanni-Vincentelli, which deals with your problem as one of the steps in heuristic minimization of DNF (and CNF) covers.

In particular, what you want is to maximally expand each cube in the cover.  In its simplest form, the problem is solved by removing a literal from a term of the DNF and checking whether the result is equivalent to the original  formula, repeating the process until no further improvement is possible.  If there weren't more to the problem, there wouldn't be a book, of course.

The result is order dependent and may contain redundant terms, including duplicates.  From a prime cover one can select a *prime and irredundant cover*, which has several interesting properties, including the fact that the cheapest DNF cover for $\phi$ under very reasonable assumptions on cost, is a prime and irredundant cover.  (This was first observed by Quine.)

Since selecting a minimum cost set of prime implicants is as hard as minimum set covering, one seldom attempts to find a solution of the true minimum cost.  Prime and irredundant covers are much easier to come by.

For that reason, the local search approach I briefly mentioned above is often preferable to the generation of all prime implicants through some variant of iterated consensus.

At the other hand of the spectrum, CNF SAT solvers, which you can think of as DNF tautology checkers, often adopt a weakened form of simplification, which does not guarantee a prime and irredundant set of clauses, but is quickly applicable to large numbers (e.g., millions) of clauses.

Comment: Could you refer me to the reason that this problem is as hard as set cover?

Comment: There's a 1965 paper by Gimpel titled "A Method of Producing a Boolean Function Having an Arbitrarily Prescribed Prime Implicant Table."  A prime implicant table is just a set covering problem.